# Avoid computing same value multiple times in Presto

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

### Sample Table :

```
╔═══════════════╗
║ dummy_data    ║
╠═══════════════╣
║ XXX_1234_YYYY ║
║ XXX_5678_YYYY ║
║ XXX_9101_YYYY ║
╚═══════════════╝
```

### Desired output :

```
╔═══════════════╦═════════════╦═════════════╗
║  dummy_data   ║ with_prefix ║ with_suffix ║
╠═══════════════╬═════════════╬═════════════╣
║ XXX_1234_YYYY ║ Pre_1234    ║ 1234_Suf    ║
║ XXX_5678_YYYY ║ Pre_5678    ║ 5678_Suf    ║
║ XXX_9101_YYYY ║ Pre_9101    ║ 9101_Suf    ║
╚═══════════════╩═════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Currently I am trying to write a `Presto Query` to use on `Amazon Athena`,

```sql
select
    dummy_data,
    'Pre_' || split(dummy_data,'_')[2] as with_prefix,
    split(dummy_data,'_')[2] || '_Suf' as with_suffix
from dummy_table
```

the above query causes `split(dummy_data,'_')[2]` to be computed two times. If there a way to avoid the double computation ? Also does Presto figure out that its the same computation and avoids recomputing ?

I am trying to avoid using *sub-query* or *With clause*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Presto does not de-decuplicate sub-expression calculations. I created feature request for this: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1070.
You can see that the expression is evaluated more than once by checking the `EXPLAIN` output (see the issue for example).

As you know, you can force de-duplication by using an inline view:

```
SELECT
    dummy_data,
    'Pre_' || sub_data  AS with_prefix,
    sub_data || '_Suf' AS with_suffix
FROM (
    SELECT
        dummy_data, 
        split(dummy_data,'_')[2] AS sub_data
    FROM (VALUES 'XXX_1234_YYYY') t(dummy_data)
);
```

Comment: Thanks I will keep an eye on the github issue.